# Какой тип хэша имеет длину в 60 символов?

Tags: хеширование

Какой тип хэша имеет длину в 60 символов?

Answer (score 2):

Например, [Blowfish](http://hash.online-convert.com/blowfish-generator). Для гугления лучше используйте длину в битах (60 байт = 480 бит)

Answer (score 1):

Любой, если не хватает длинный разбейте на части и возьмите хэш от каждой части, а лишнее отрежьте.

**UPD**

```
// С#
var str = "Hello";
var str1 = str.Substring(0, str.Length / 2); // Первая половина строки
var str2 = str.Substring(str.Length / 2); // Вторая половина строки
var hash = (md5(str1) + md5(str2)).SubString(0, 60);

// Длинна md5 равна 32 символа    
// Складываем два хэша и отрезаем последние 4 символа
// md5("He") = a64cf5823262686e1a28b2245be34ce0
// md5("llo") = 7062da7393ecc31c3c0564020f85efd1
// hash = a64cf5823262686e1a28b2245be34ce07062da7393ecc31c3c0564020f85
// Профит!
```

Comment: Предоставьте плз пример 60-символьного MD5?)

Comment: Например remixsid (кука вконтакте)

Comment: Не поможет)))

Answer (score -1):

Например remixsid (кука вконтакте)